# Parallelogram with linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $F: \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ be a linear map such that $F(e_1)=(1,1)$ and $F(e_2)=(-1,2)$. Determinate $F(0,0),F(1,0),F(0,1),F(1,1)$ and demonstrate that is a parallelogram. How can show this?

Comment: In English, we say "map" instead of "application".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can be a solution of the problem.
Every vector $v \in \Bbb R^2$ can be written as $v=x(1,0)+y(0,1)= (x,y)$
therefore $$F(x(1,0)+y(0,1))= x(1,1)+y(-1,2)=(x-y,x+2y)$$
For this motivation the vector $(1,1)$ can be written as $(1,1)=(x,y)$
with $x=y=1$ therefore $$F(1,1)=(0,3)$$
also the other vector can be written in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look at the vectors created by 
$F(1,1)-F(0,1)$ , $F(1,1)-F(1,0)$ , $F(1,0)-F(0,0)$ , $F(0,1)-F(0,0)$